# drupal 7 jquery selector does not work

Tags: javascript, drupal-7

i want to alert something when i click one text filed in drupal 7. Here is my code:

```
(function ($) { 
$("#edit-arrival-city").click(function(){
    alert("fe");
});

})(jQuery);
```

It does not work, and there is no error in firebug. But this code works:

```
(function ($) { 
alert("something");

})(jQuery);
```

The textfield is:

```
<input id="edit-arrival-city" class="form-text required form-autocomplete jquery-once-1-processed" type="text" maxlength="128" size="20" value="Arrival City" name="arrival_city" autocomplete="OFF" aria-autocomplete="list">
```

The js code is in my_module folder and it is added in my_module.info: scripts[] = js/myjs.js
Thanks very much.

Comment: Does the element exist on the page at the time when you attach the event listener?

Comment: I think (function ($) { })(jQuery); is same as document.ready, right?

Comment: nope. That's an [iffy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) with jQuery passed as parameter. The domready shorthand looks like `$(function() {});`. ;-)

Comment: OMG,you saved my life!!! you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, I assume that your element doesn't exist on the page when you attach the event listener. This would work fine if your javascript snippet is embedded after the element (e.g. right before the closing `</body>`. If it's not you would need to wrap it in a [domReady](http://api.jquery.com/ready) function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#edit-arrival-city").click(function(){
         alert("fe");
    });
});
```

Even better would be to use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/), this way you can omit the domReady because the click target is evaluated when the event happens:

```
$(document).on("click", "#edit-arrival-city", function(e) {
    alert("fe");
});
```

And just ftr, your posted example is an [iffy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `jQuery` instead `$`
For this case [jQuery :contains() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_contains) need use 
not

```
drupal_add_js('
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("p:contains(is)").css("background-color", "yellow");
            });
        ', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'defer' => TRUE));
```

but

```
drupal_add_js('
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("p:contains(is)").css("background-color", "yellow");
            });
        ', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'defer' => TRUE));
```

And not need

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com
```